# Replace values in a dataframe column that are below a certain threshold with NaN

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, nan, nonetype

Let's say I have the following sample dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [4, 0.2, 3, 0.5], 'B': ['red', 'white', 'blue', 'green']})

     A      B
0  4.0    red
1  0.2  white
2  3.0   blue
3  0.5  green
```

I am trying to replace entries in a column that are below a certain threshold with NaN to look like the following:

```
     A      B
0  4.0    red
1  NaN  white
2  3.0   blue
3  NaN  green
```

Here is my attempt:

```
cutoff = 2
df['A'] = df['A'].apply(lambda x: [y if y > cutoff else None for y in x])
```

And the error I receive:

```
TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable
```

Where have I gone wrong? I assume it has to do with the `None` type

Comment: Can you show your sample data and expected output ?

Comment: `df['A'] = df['A'].where(df['A']>cutoff)`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`np.where`

```
df['A'] = np.where(df['A']<=cutoff , np.nan, df['A'])
```

Answer (score 1):

Does the code below work for you? I used `.loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value` to modify the dataframe ([link to the documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html?highlight=loc#pandas.DataFrame.loc))

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [4, 0.2, 3, 0.5], 'B': ['red', 'white', 'blue', 'green']})
df.loc[df['A'] < 1, 'A'] = np.nan
print(df)
```

Output:

```
     A      B
0  4.0    red
1  NaN  white
2  3.0   blue
3  NaN  green
```

Answer (score 1):

Try instead:

```
df['A'] = df2['A'].apply(lambda x: x if x > cutoff else None)
```